# php artisan serve get cached or does not react while updating code in Laravel 5.5. After a restart, it works again each time

Tags: php, laravel, caching

My IDE is phpstorm and running on WAMP Server. While coding, it does not show the expected response, **always returns the previously requested response** (In postman). Each time, I need to close 'php artisan serve' with CTRL+C and then run again to get the expected response.

I tried changing IDE, changing port but it does not work. Of course, I tired to save manually ( CTRL+S) but the problem persists.
I also tried the following commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
composer dump
```

But the problem still persists.

Comment: If you have wamp then why are you using `php artisan serve` ? use `php artisan serve --port 8080` to run it on another port.

Comment: I tried different ports except 8000 but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be the composer command. Please, have a look on my setup in the Makefile:

```
run:
    php artisan config:cache
    php artisan config:clear
    php artisan cache:clear
    composer.phar dump-autoload -o
    php artisan serve
```

And it's ready to go with a Laravel's "clean build".

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with a diferent request tool, like doing a GET on your browser?
Or just create a new endpoint to test that. This way you make sure that changes are being saved.

I recommend you make tests to see if:

1. the problem is on your postman (a cache maybe?);
2. the problem is that your code isn't being saved;
3. the problem is on your local server (a persistent cache?);

My tip is: Try to eliminate the possible causes and you should achieve an answer.

Let´s try to make sure about above items and if them are ok, we check possible another ones.